# How to know some object's order in django queryset

Tags: python, django

```
qs1 = QueryModel.objects.all().order_by('?')

obj1 = QueryModel.objects.get(pk=123)

def order_stuff(queryset, obj)
    return print(#obj_order_from_queryset)
order_stuff(qs1, obj1) >>> some ordering number
```

How to know some object's order on some queryset?

For example, if queryset are like:

```
print(qs1) >>> {'pk': 1}, {'pk': 3}, {'pk': 4}, {'pk': 123} ...
```

So that:

```
order_stuff(qs1, obj1) >>> 4
```

if queryset are like:

```
print(qs1) >>> {'pk': 123}, {'pk': 3}, {'pk': 4}, {'pk': 13} ...
```

So that:

```
order_stuff(qs1, obj1) >>> 1
```

if queryset are like:

```
print(qs1) >>> {'pk': 13}, {'pk': 123}, {'pk': 4}, {'pk': 13} ...
```

So that:

```
order_stuff(qs1, obj1) >>> 2
```

How to do this?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @Borut I'll make some queryset not using `order_by('?')`. I have to find specific user's order in some queryset. For example, to check whether user `anne1` is the first user from `User.objects.filter(name__contains='anne1').order_by('userprofile__height')`

Comment: Why would you want that? You can loop through objects in queryset and determine the position this way, but why would you need to know the position of an object in a queryset?

Comment: @Borut Because I want to know specific user's height rank from all users by conditional options.

Comment: You use [database window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#window-functions) to rank elements.